# Как сделать ограничение на ввод по времени?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, время, таймер, task

Т.е. если в течении какого то времени не был введен правильный ответ (theard или task?), то переменной основного потока передается какое то значение. Этот код не работает, т.к. string test = await PrintAsync(); блокирует основной поток в ожидании значения

```
class Program
    {

        async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            string test = await PrintAsync();
            async Task <string> PrintAsync()
            {
                await Task.Delay(3000);
                string name = "";
                return name;
            }
            while (true)
            {
                if(test=="")
                {
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Ввод ответа");
                string text = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("ответ" + text);

            }

        }
       
    }
```

Comment: Как минимум, укажите язык программирования в метках к вопросу. Также добавьте попытки, как именно вы пытались сделать.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Распишите более чётко `use case`. Сейчас не очень понятно что и как должно всё-таки происходить. А так возможно вам нужно использовать `Task.Run` https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run

Comment: Мне нужно прервать while если ответ не удовлетворит требованиям. Проверка ответа происходит на сервере. Эта строка if(test=="") выглядит вот такif(test=="" || ans=="ok" )

Comment: CrazyElf. За подсказку спасибо!. Я не знаю что применить, потоки, ассинхроность, выделить в отдельную задачу. Или комбинация нескольких

Comment: Нет, вы всё-таки для начала чётко распишите в вопросе условия: сколько времени даётся на ответ? сколько попыток даётся? а время даётся на одну попытку или на все вместе взятые? и т.д. Сейчас задача не очень чётко поставлена.

Comment: Спасибо всем за рассуждения. Общая задача. Нужно написать серверную  игру в "Города".  на сервере происходит проверка. Клиент получает сообщения ответ принят или нет. Если игрок не успел за определенное время правильно ответить игрок выбывает из игры, Можно даже разорвать соединение. и кода бы хотелось на это затратить в пределах 20 -30 строк. Все коменты обязательно изучу

Comment: По поводу клиент-сервера, [вот примеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+tcplistener)

Comment: Уставший мозг выдал. Даже если получить из параллельного потока нужное значение. Это значение  в цикле проверки ответа, будет ждать активации цикла. Активация цикла - ответ сервера. Но если игрок не не отправить вызов серверу, сервер не отправит ответ. Цикл не будет активирован. Вообщем. Пару дней надо отдохнуть.

Comment: aepot. Вам отдельное спасибо за предоставленный код!